# After jenkins job complete, the service also down

Tags: shell, jenkins, jobs

I have met a problem.

I used Jenkins to install haproxy and start the service, but after the job complete, the executor is free, and the haproxy daemon also disappear.

if I use sleep 30s after the service start, and the haproxy service will also alive at the 30s, after that, the haproxy daemon will down.

Comment: There's no question here.

Comment: apparently you need to adapt jenkins job config, question is rather unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behaviour is by design, as explained in [ProcessTreeKiller](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/ProcessTreeKiller). To avoid daemons spawned by the Jenkins build being terminated, add

```
export BUILD_ID=dontKillMe
```

to the beginning of your shell step.

Comment: Yes, you said it. But I do not want to add this to every shell in my job, So I had test with the slave machine env parameter, also add java -DprocessTreeDisabled=True(Such this) to /etc/sysconfig/jenkins, but they didn't work. The only way was to add this to the machine's ~/.bashrc file. Any Suggested if we can add something to the jenkins config, not the slave machine or the job shell?